# Failure to multiple file upload in froms in Asp.Net Core Mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

i was want to creating a multiple image upload file.i  want to create just like this: http://learningprogramming.net/net/asp-net-core-mvc/multiple-file-upload-in-forms-in-asp-net-core-mvc/

so similarly when i create a model and did migration.then i found an error.

test.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Practise.Models
{
    public class test
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public List<string> Photos { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Error:

[image]

for that i can't be take step to create multiple file upload.how i solve that problem.

Comment: What didn't you understand about the error, exactly? Logically you can't save a list inside a single field in a database. That's essentially what entity framework is telling you, in it's long-winded way. If you want to store a list of photos against a single database record, then you'll need a second table which has a foreign key back to the first one, and you put the photo data in rows in that table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a one to many relationship,one test to many photos,so you need to have two tables in the db.
You can set model like this:

```
public class test
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public List<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
    }
public class Photo
    {
        public string PhotoId { get; set; }
        public string Path { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: all is good when i used your process..but when i used this line for add image  ```product.Photos.Add(photo.FileName); ```  then i found a simple error: ```Can not Covert To String From Practise.model.photo```can you solve that?

Comment: Do you mean product is a test model ？If so,it needs to add Photo model to it rather than a string.You can use product.Photos.Add(photo);